# How does the 'Keen Edge' ability work?

Tags: guild-wars-2

On my Ranger I have an ability called 'Sharpening Stone', as follows;

[image]

I also have a trait called 'Keen Edge', which is supposed to trigger Sharpening Stone automatically whenever I reach 75% health - according to the text;

[image]

However, I have never seen Sharpening Stone go on cooldown unless I have specifically used the ability. Is this how Keen Edge is supposed to work, or am I missing something?

Comment: When your health goes below 75% you should see the buff icon for Sharpening Stone (above your utility skills).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keen Edge (and other similar "Use [ability] when [X happens]" traits) grant you the effects of Sharpening Stone for free, automatically, when your health drops below 75%.

It doesn't matter if your actual Sharpening Stone ability is on cooldown, or even if it isn't on your action bar.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that those traits tend to have internal cooldowns of their own - often not mentioned in the tooltip, and not necessarily the same as the cooldown of the ability itself.